# Таймер win32 на С++

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте, выполняю задания на С++ и всё хорошо, только вот проблема с таймером. Вот кусок самого задания:

> Необходимо определить в классе view2 статический метод ontimeraction. Этот метод отображает на экране заданный наследник data. Выбрать для этого win32 таймер собственный интервал повторных вызовов. Установить реализованный метод view::ontimeraction(), на вызов в таймере. Таймер должен сработать всего 4 раза. Метод должен выводить на экран данные про текущий ассоциируемый объект данных.

Дата — просто класс с данными, а view — его логика для графического отображения этих данных. Прошу помочь объяснить, как это всё сделать и, если можно, набросать эту функцию ну или хотя бы псевдокод с объяснением что куда. Я гуглил, но как-то не могу понять, как прикрутить сюда тот таймер с англ. [статьи на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644901(v=vs.85).aspx). Всегда были у меня проблемы со всякими специфическими ф-циями WinAPI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я разобрался в данном вопросе покопав источники и подёргав друзей, предлагаю вам 3 решения(я в них разобрался но вам подробный комментарий не оставлю, с помощью гугла всё разбирается за 10 минут построчно).
1 способ:

```
struct TimerParam {
    int firstValueToDisplay;
    int secondValueToDisplay;
    int numCntActions;
};
int timer(UINT ms, TimerParam param) {
    // Pointer to timer object.
    PTP_TIMER pTimer;
    // Parameters to be passed to callback.
    TimerParam timerParam = param;

    ULARGE_INTEGER ulDueTime;
    FILETIME fileDueTime;

    ulDueTime.QuadPart = -10000 * (ULONGLONG) ms;
    fileDueTime.dwHighDateTime = ulDueTime.HighPart;
    fileDueTime.dwLowDateTime = ulDueTime.LowPart;

    pTimer = CreateThreadpoolTimer(onTimerAction, (PVOID) &timerParam, 0);
    if (NULL == pTimer) {
        printf("CreateThreadpoolTimer failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    // Set a timer to wait for ms milliseconds.
    SetThreadpoolTimer(pTimer, &fileDueTime, ms, 0);

    printf("Waiting for %d ms %d times.\n", ms, timerParam.numCntActions);

    // Wait for the timer.
    while (timerParam.numCntActions) {
        Sleep(500);
    }

    // Do this to prevent callback calling.
    SetThreadpoolTimer(pTimer, 0, 0, 0);
    WaitForThreadpoolTimerCallbacks(pTimer, true);

    // Finally close timer.
    CloseThreadpoolTimer(pTimer);

    printf("Timer was signaled.\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Второй способ:

```
VOID CALLBACK TimerProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT_PTR idEvent, DWORD dwTime) {
        printf("Timer was signaled.\n");
    }


int timer(UINT ms, int numCntActions) {
    // Set the timer.
    UINT_PTR timer = SetTimer(NULL, NULL, ms, (TIMERPROC) TimerProc);
    if (NULL == timer) {
        printf("SetTimer failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for %d ms...\n", ms);
    MSG msg;

    while (numCntActions--) {
        GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (0 == KillTimer(NULL, timer)) {
        printf("KillTimer failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

void CALLBACK onTimerAction(PTP_CALLBACK_INSTANCE instance, PVOID param,
        PTP_TIMER timer) {
    TimerParam *par;
    par = (TimerParam *) param;
    if (par->numCntActions-- > 0) {

        printf("Timer: %i, %i\n", par->firstValueToDisplay,
                par->secondValueToDisplay);
    }
}
```

3 способ:

```
int timer1(int ms, int numCntActions) {
    HANDLE hTimer = NULL;
    LARGE_INTEGER liDueTime;

    liDueTime.QuadPart = -10000 * (ULONGLONG) ms;

    // Create a waitable timer.
    hTimer = CreateWaitableTimer(NULL, TRUE, L"WaitableTimer");
    if (NULL == hTimer) {
        printf("CreateWaitableTimer failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Waiting for %d ms...\n", ms);

    while (numCntActions--) {
        // Set a timer to wait for ms milliseconds.
        if (!SetWaitableTimer(hTimer, &liDueTime, 0, NULL, NULL, 0)) {
            printf("SetWaitableTimer failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
            return 2;
        }

        // Wait for the timer.
        if (WaitForSingleObject(hTimer, INFINITE) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
            printf("WaitForSingleObject failed (%lu)\n", GetLastError());
        } else {
            printf("Timer was signaled.\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вашу задачу можно решить двумя способами:

1. Оконными таймерами.

   Для использования данного способа требуется владение хотя бы одним окном. Созданный таймер привязывается к этому окну и посылает ему сообщения [`WM_TIMER`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/ms644902(v=vs.85).aspx).

   Так как однократно срабатывающие таймеры создать таким образом невозможно, нам придётся самостоятельно отслеживать количество срабатываний, учитывая при этом, что [между последним срабатыванием таймера и его остановкой нам может прийти ещё один `WM_TIMER`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141205-00/?p=43463), но [не более](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20141204-00/?p=43473). Подобное происходит при большом потоке оконных сообщений, так как у `WM_TIMER` самый низкий приоритет обработки.

   Для работы с данным видом таймеров вам потребуется:

   - добавить в конструктор `view2`вызов `SetTimer()`,
   - в (уже имеющемся) обработчике оконных сообщений (который WindowProc) при приёме `WM_TIMER`:

     - проверять ранее объявленный счётчик срабатываний таймера;
     - если счётчик больше порогового значения, вызвать `KillTimer()`;
     - увеличить значение вышеупомянутого счётчика;
     - вызвать вашу `view2::ontimeraction`;
   - вызывать `KillTimer()` в деструкторе `view2` не надо. Таймер и так будет уничтожен либо явно в `WM_TIMER`, либо неявно при уничтожении окна и его очереди сообщений.

     ```
         class view2
         {
             unsigned timerFiresCount;
             HWND hwndView;

             static void ontimeraction()
             {
                 // ...
             }

             static LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
                 HWND   hwnd,
                 UINT   uMsg,
                 WPARAM wParam,
                 LPARAM lParam
              )
              {
                  switch(uMsg)
                  {
                      case WM_TIMER:
                         if(timerFiresCount < 4)
                         {
                             if(++timerFiresCount == 4)
                                 KillTimer(hwnd, 1);
                             ontimeraction();
                         }
                         return 0;

                      // ...
                  }
              }

         public:
             view2()
                 : timerFiresCount(0)
             {
                 // Выполняете здесь инициализацию класса и создание окна для вида.
                 // Пусть HWND этого вида сохраняется в hwndView.

                 // Идентификатор таймера может быть любым кроме нулевого (NULL)
                 SetTimer(hwndView, 1, ИНТЕРВАЛ_СРАБАТЫВАНИЯ, NULL);
             }
         };
     ```
2. Очередями таймеров (timer queues). Однако в данном случае функция обратного вызова исполняется не в главном потоке, что вынуждает создавать довольно громоздкую обвязку для пересылки уведомления в главный поток, где и должен выполняться `ontimeraction()`. Можно, конечно, обойтись и без пересылки, но тогда придётся огораживать всё примитивами синхронизации, что тоже является излишеством.

Comment: Расскажите про 2 так как программа консольная не имеет окон и в дальнейших заданиях его нет.

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk, ваша программа запрашивает у пользователя какой-нибудь ввод? Если нет, то можно создать невидимое окно, задав ему `HWND_MESSAGE` в качестве родителя и начать крутить цикл обработки событий, придя таким образом к первому варианту.

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk, если же пользователь всё-таки должен что-то вводить, то вы всё равно не сможете перейти к таймеру до того, как пользователь завершит ввод и нажмёт *Enter*. В этом случае также создаёте окно, но цикл оконных сообщений надо крутить уже после каждого использования `std::cin` до исчерпания очереди сообщений (то есть использовать уже `PeekMessage()` и продолжать дальнейшую работу, когда он вернёт ноль).

Comment: Он ничего не вводит, просто нужен этот идиотский таймер(

Comment: ну может поможете пжлст а то не к кому больше обратится(

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk, то, что программа консольная, не мешает вам создать из `int main()` невидимое окно для приёма таймерных сообщений (только задайте его родителя в константу `HWND_MESSAGE`) и запустить очередь событий так же как и для графического приложения. Единственная разница — у вас в наличии будет предварительно созданное консольное окно.